# Time limit exceed

Tags: c++, vector, graph

The system said: my code was time limit exceed. Is there away to shortcut my code?
  I'm using vector to save nails to graph.

Input: e,n
Output: checkcase=1 => Check u adjacent with i
        checkcase=2 => find nails that around u

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int e, n;
  string u, i;
  //using vectors
  vector<string> graph;
  //use list
  list<string>listElementsInCase2;

  cin >> e;
  cin >> n;
  //loop for e
  for (long index = 0; index < e; index++)
  {
    cin>>u>> i;
    //add u to graph 
    graph.push_back(u);
    //add i to graph 
    graph.push_back(i);
  }
  //Option
  int checkCase;
  long index;
   //loop for n
    while(sizeof(n))
  {
    cin >> checkCase;

    if (checkCase == 1)
    {
        cin >> u >> i;

        for (index = 0; index < 2 * e; index += 2)
        {   //Check u adjacent ? i
            if ((graph.at(index) == u) && (graph.at(index + 1) == i))
            {
                cout << "TRUE" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (index == 2 * e)
            cout << "FALSE" << endl;
    }
    //checkCase=2
    if (checkCase == 2)
    {
        cin >> u;

        for (long index = 0; index < 2 * e; index += 2)
        {   
            if (graph.at(index) == u)
                listElementsInCase2.push_back(graph.at(index + 1));
        }
          // return 0
        if (listElementsInCase2.empty() == true)
            cout << "0";
        else
        {
            while (0 < listElementsInCase2.size())
            {   //find nails that around u
                cout << listElementsInCase2.front();
                listElementsInCase2.pop_front();
                cout << " ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    n--;
   }
 }
//end
```

Comment: "find nails that balcony with u" makes no sense at all. Are you using a computer to translate for you?

Comment: And a hint about what the input is and what the program is supposed to accomplish would be a good idea.

Comment: probably a better candidate for codereview.stackexchange.com  rather than this site?

Comment: Well...  `while(sizeof(n))` is not going to terminate ever.

Comment: Can I suggest you get a c++ book and look up how to write functions?

Comment: Yes, it is useful for me @UKMonkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have an infinite while loop in your code.

Your statement `while(sizeof(n))` will never stop repeating the loop since sizeof(n) always returns the byte size of the type integer, which is always a positive number and thus always evaluates as true.

A shortcut for your code would be to replace the while loop with a for or while loop that actually ends at some point. Also sizeof is probably not the function you want.

`for(int i=0; i<n; i++){` might be what you are looking for.